# Receiving byte stream using TCPClient consuming too much CPU

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have a service which receives large byte streams from 3rd party systems using a `TcpListener`. Unfortunately, I don't have the option to change protocols or to something like `WCF`.

When lots of systems are sending data at the same time, the CPU usage on my server spikes to nearly 90% and causes problems for other services. After taking a profile of my service, it looks like the CPU is being used reading the byte arrays from the `NetworkStream` into a `MemoryStream`. Here's an example of my server code

```
public void StartListening(CancellationToken token) {
    var listener = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);
    listener.Start();

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) {
        var socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(socket);
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        Task.Run(()=> ReadStream(stream, token));
    }
}

private void ReadStream(NetworkStream stream, CancellationToken token){
    int offset = 0;
    int size = EXPECTED_FILE_SIZE;
    var inStream = new MemoryStream(size);
    while (size > 0 && !token.IsCancellationRequested) {
        try {
            int readin = stream.Read(inStream.GetBuffer(), offset, size);
            size -= readin;
            offset += readin;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }    
    }
    //Do something with the memory stream
}
```

I wrote a test client which sends multiple byte streams to the service at a time and every time the CPU spikes. I've tried a few things server side to fix the issue (including using `BeginRead` and `EndRead` on the network stream). The only thing that seems to help is when I send larger chunks of the byte streams from the client, but I have no control over the 3rd party systems which send the data.

I have thought that it might work to accept all socket connections, but then limit the number of "ReadStream" tasks, but I don't know if there are any detrimental effects of accepting a socket and then not reading from it for a while.

Comment: Not sure of the actual problem as the code itself looks correct, my only concern is what if `EXPECTED_FILE_SIZE` is larger than what is actually transmitted?  Your code will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: You are using cancellation tokens, but synchronous reads. Question: why are you using synchronous reads? Socket IO is pretty much a perfect candidate for async reads. Also, are you the client or the server here? If you're the server: Kestrel and Pipelines are *built* for this scenario, making massively concurrent servers a breeze to write. Pipelines is also designed to handle back-buffers etc for you, so you don't end up copying everything to a MemoryStream. 
I have a 4 part blog that covers this, here:  https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html

Comment: If you are the server, then: using thread-per-connection answers the question "why am I haemorrhaging CPU?". Async is the key in writing scalable servers. In particular, your current code is tying up the thread-pool, which is a terrible idea for a whole pile of reasons

Comment: This is the server side code. Thanks for the tip on Kestrel, more and more this service is looking to be a rewrite. As for being synchronous, I didn't write the original code, but I did try converting the Read calls to their BeginRead and EndRead equivalents (using FromAsync instead of Task.Run) and it didn't improve things much

Comment: You are missing `async` `await` everywhere, so it's unsurprising. `Task.Run` in a loop does not async make.

Comment: The Task.Run in my example is just so the service can continue to accept sockets at the same time that one of the connections is being read. When I converted to BeginRead and EndRead using FromAsync, I did use async await

Answer (score 0):

instead of continuously reading the stream use an async call back like the one built in so it only calls when needed, you could do something like

```html
public void StartListening(CancellationToken token)
{
    var listener = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);
    listener.Start();

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(socket);
        stream = tcpClient.GetStream(); //you need to have the stream declared at the start of the program

        //set it up with th receive callback called RecieveCallback
        //the 4096 is just so that any data more than that won't be read but it is highly unlickely for a peice of data above 4096 to appear
        stream.BeginRead(4096, 0, 4096, ReceiveCallback, null);

        Task.Run(() => ReadStream(stream, token));
    }
}
//then we setup the RecieveCallback event
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult _result)
{
    try
    {
        int _byteLength = stream.EndRead(_result); //find how much data it is
        if (_byteLength <= 0)
        {
            //if this is true you are disconnected
            return;
        }

        byte[] _data = new byte[_byteLength];
        Array.Copy(4096, _data, _byteLength);

        DoSomethingWith(_data)
        stream.BeginRead(4096, 0, 4096, ReceiveCallback, null); //start listening again
    }
    catch
    {
        //disconnect
    }
}
```

By the way running the code snippet won't work, it was the only way form me to write out the code in a way that it would look good

Comment: Async is not faster. It's more scalable. I also rather use async, but it depends on how many clients.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try to solve it by creating a separate BackgroundWorker for each connection that dies when finished. That would let you make a better use of CPU threads making the OS scheduler handle it.

It could also be that the CPU is not powerful enough to handle so many incoming data at that many times.

Otherwise, i would use a Gateway which gets the data and sends it to a RabbitMQ queue, and process that data at lower speeds.

Comment: A thread per connection is not much scalable. There are better way for server side.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen In that case you could use a load balancer, assuming you can have multiple instances of this one, like NGINX. Still, i'd suggest using multiple workers or async programming. I would like to know more about the architecture though.

Comment: no, using a loadbalancer will not fix the cpu thread choking.